# Contain .jq Filter Results Into a Single Array

Tags: json, jq

With the following input example:

```
{"contacts":{"orgid":"1","email":"janedoe@aol.com","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","phone":"4045551212","tags":["tag1","tag2"],"fields":[{"id":"2","value":"IB4220"},{"id":"3","value":"1994-05-18"},{"id":"12","value":"CONSULTANT"},{"id":"13","value":"janedoe@aol.com"},{"id":"6","value":"111 Main Blvd"},{"id":"7","value":"Babylon"},{"id":"8","value":"NY"},{"id":"9","value":"11702-1522"},{"id":"10","value":"US"},{"id":"11","value":""},{"id":"5","value":"http://www.something.com/janedoe"}]}}
{"contacts":{"orgid":"1","email":"janedoe@aol.com","first_name":"Jane","last_name":"Doe","phone":"4045551212","tags":["tag1","tag2"],"fields":[{"id":"2","value":"IB4220"},{"id":"3","value":"1994-05-18"},{"id":"12","value":"CONSULTANT"},{"id":"13","value":"janedoe@aol.com"},{"id":"6","value":"111 Main Blvd"},{"id":"7","value":"Babylon"},{"id":"8","value":"NY"},{"id":"9","value":"11702-1522"},{"id":"10","value":"US"},{"id":"11","value":""},{"id":"5","value":"http://www.something.com/janedoe"}]}}
```

I am trying to contain my filter result in a single "contacts" array.

Here is my jq filter I am working with to no avail...

```
jq --slurp '.[] | .[].fields[].id |= tonumber | .[].orgid |= tonumber | {contacts: [.[]| {orgid: .["orgid"],email: .["email"],first_name: .["first_name"],last_name: .["last_name"],phone: .["phone"],tags:[ .["tags"]],fields}]}'
```

It wraps each input line in a "contacts" array like follows...

```
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "orgid": 1,
      "email": "janedoe@aol.com",
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "phone": "4045551212",
      "tags": [
        [
          "tag1",
          "tag2"
        ]
      ],
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "value": "IB4220"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "value": "1994-05-18"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "value": "CONSULTANT"
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "value": "janedoe@aol.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "value": "111 Main Blvd"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "value": "Babylon"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "value": "NY"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "value": "11702-1522"
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "value": "US"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "value": "http://www.something.com/janedoe"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
{
  "contacts": [
    {
      "orgid": 1,
      "email": "janedoe@aol.com",
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "phone": "4045551212",
      "tags": [
        [
          "tag1",
          "tag2"
        ]
      ],
      "fields": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "value": "IB4220"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "value": "1994-05-18"
        },
        {
          "id": 12,
          "value": "CONSULTANT"
        },
        {
          "id": 13,
          "value": "janedoe@aol.com"
        },
        {
          "id": 6,
          "value": "111 Main Blvd"
        },
        {
          "id": 7,
          "value": "Babylon"
        },
        {
          "id": 8,
          "value": "NY"
        },
        {
          "id": 9,
          "value": "11702-1522"
        },
        {
          "id": 10,
          "value": "US"
        },
        {
          "id": 11,
          "value": ""
        },
        {
          "id": 5,
          "value": "http://www.something.com/janedoe"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

... But I need it like this (1 "contacts" array containing all the filtered input lines)...

```
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "orgid": "1",
            "email": "janedoe@aol.com",
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "phone": "4045551212",
            "tags": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ],
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "value": "IB4220"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "value": "1994-05-18"
                },
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "value": "CONSULTANT"
                },
                {
                    "id": "13",
                    "value": "janedoe@aol.com"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "value": "111 Main Blvd"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "value": "Babylon"
                },
                {
                    "id": "8",
                    "value": "NY"
                },
                {
                    "id": "9",
                    "value": "11702-1522"
                },
                {
                    "id": "10",
                    "value": "US"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "value": "http://www.something.com/janedoe"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orgid": "1",
            "email": "janedoe@aol.com",
            "first_name": "Jane",
            "last_name": "Doe",
            "phone": "4045551212",
            "tags": [
                "tag1",
                "tag2"
            ],
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "value": "IB4220"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "value": "1994-05-18"
                },
                {
                    "id": "12",
                    "value": "CONSULTANT"
                },
                {
                    "id": "13",
                    "value": "janedoe@aol.com"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "value": "111 Main Blvd"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "value": "Babylon"
                },
                {
                    "id": "8",
                    "value": "NY"
                },
                {
                    "id": "9",
                    "value": "11702-1522"
                },
                {
                    "id": "10",
                    "value": "US"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "value": ""
                },
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "value": "http://www.something.com/janedoe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the "expected" output as shown, you could use the following jq filter in conjunction with the -s option:

```
{ contacts: [.[] | [.contacts]] | add }
```

However, your jq program indicates you also want to convert some strings to numbers.  That is q.e.d. along the lines you suggest and is thus left as an exercise, but a complete solution using an alternative approach is shown below.

### Avoiding --slurp

In general, it's better to use -n with `inputs`:

```
[ [inputs.contacts 
   | .fields[].id |= tonumber
   | .orgid |= tonumber] ]
| {contacts: add}
```

Comment: I like the minimal approach.  When I tried it, I only get the second line output though.  Even when I add a 3rd and 4th line of input data, only the 2nd line returns. Ideas?

Comment: Assuming you are using the "Avoiding --slurp" solution, the only explanation I can think of is that (a) you forgot the -n command-line option; and (b) you wrote `input` instead of `inputs`.

Comment: You are correct, I left off the -n part when I removed the -s part. Thanks for all your help.